# get url opengraph data

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph, yahoo-mail

Are there any good tutorials where you can see how to use javascript to get opengraph data from a url, like the way facebook does if you paste a link into your post's textarea, or how yahoo mail does (like facebook) when you paste a url into your mail.

I have googled this for an hour now with all kinds of keywords and can't find anything. Does anyone know of tutorials on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post maybe it can help you but need jQuery & PHP. I don't know you can use PHP or not

http://redsunsoft.com/2011/01/parse-link-like-facebook-with-jquery-and-php/

Demo

http://redsunsoft.com/demo/link_parser/

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks... after looking at how yahoo mail does it I see some kind of server checking is rquired. It doesn't seem like you can do this just via ajax, getting the page and parsing the content.